# list align problem

Tags: math-mode, lists, align

Basically, I was wondering if someone can help me align the letters of the list as it looks wonky when on the page? I have managed to align the `vdots` with the arrow but the letter w looks uneven beneath the letter E:

```
\begin{align*}
E &\rightarrow H \\
N &\rightarrow Q \\
E &\rightarrow H \\
M &\rightarrow P \\
Y &\rightarrow B \\
  & \vdotswithin{\rightarrow} \\
W &\rightarrow Z \\
E &\rightarrow H \\
S &\rightarrow V \\
T &\rightarrow W \\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I would prefer if it looked like this, but with the `vdots` underneath the arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `array` environment with either 3 centered (`c`) columns or with the left- and right-hand columns left-aligned (`l`) (and the middle one still of type `c`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % optional; default is 5pt
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
E &\to& H \\
N &\to& Q \\
E &\to& H \\
M &\to& P \\
Y &\to& B \\
  &\vdots&\\
W &\to& Z \\
E &\to& H \\
S &\to& V \\
T &\to& W 
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{lcl}
E &\to& H \\
N &\to& Q \\
E &\to& H \\
M &\to& P \\
Y &\to& B \\
  &\vdots&\\
W &\to& Z \\
E &\to& H \\
S &\to& V \\
T &\to& W 
\end{array}
\]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is with a TABstack.  Since this looks like an alphabetic transliteration rather than a math equation, I left the results in text, rather than math, mode.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\def\RAr{${}\rightarrow{}$}
\tabbedLongstack{
E & \RAr & H\\
N & \RAr & Q\\
E & \RAr & H\\
M & \RAr & P\\
Y & \RAr & B\\
  & \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\vdots} & \\
W & \RAr & Z\\
E & \RAr & H\\
S & \RAr & V\\
T & \RAr & W
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]